# Testflight tab keeps hang, does not load

Tags: testflight

When I switch to the TestFlight tab for my app in iTunes Connect, it doesn't load. It perpetually shows the spinner.

It was doing this yesterday too. I've tried a different browser and it's the same.

Any ideas?[image]

Web Console shows the following error :

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.tfGroupsService.internalGroup.id')
value@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/controllers/tfLink:2:318716
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/controllers/tfLink:2:321777
g@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:24610
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:24782
$digest@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:30917
$apply@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:14:657
i@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:7085
u@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:9007
onload@https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.84585ca92f.js:13:9479

Comment: I’m consistently experiencing the same issue during the last few days as well. I called Apple Developer Support and they told me there is no workaround, but that the TestFlight portal should start working again within the next 24 hours

Comment: What do they mention about Test-flight maintenance ?

Comment: Not much. But I’ve verified that the issue was isolated to the particular app connect tenant I’m using. I logged in with another Apple ID and TestFlight management worked fine

Comment: I have just reported the case with my App ID to Apple . Let’s see how Apple replies

Comment: The TestFlight management portal is up and running again now, at least for our tenant

Comment: That’s weird but as long as it is working , everything will be fine .

Comment: Same behavior again today